# Preg_Match_All Multiple

Tags: preg-match-all

I want to take data from a website with preg_match_all: DAY, TIME and TITLE. Each day is divided into two parts, I want to join the two parts in a single code, per individual day. Thank you in advance for any help

```
<div id="PARTEA-1"> // Prima parte

<tr>
<td class="data">luni (1.1.1970)</td>
<td class="data">marti (2.1.1970)</td>
<td class="data">miercuri (3.1.1970)</td>
<td class="data">joi (4.1.1970)</td>
<td class="data">vineri (5.1.1970)</td>
</tr>

<tbody>
<tr><td class="ora">07:00</td> <td class="title">Mic dejun</td></tr>
<tr><td class="ora">12:00</td> <td class="title">Pranz</td></tr>
<tr><td class="ora">19:00</td> <td class="title">Cina</td></tr>
</tbody>

<tbody>
<tr><td class="ora">07:00</td> <td class="title">Mic dejun</td></tr>
<tr><td class="ora">12:00</td> <td class="title">Pranz</td></tr>
<tr><td class="ora">19:00</td> <td class="title">Cina</td></tr>
</tbody>

<tbody>
<tr><td class="ora">07:00</td> <td class="title">Mic dejun</td></tr>
<tr><td class="ora">12:00</td> <td class="title">Pranz</td></tr>
<tr><td class="ora">19:00</td> <td class="title">Cina</td></tr>
</tbody>

<tbody>
<tr><td class="ora">07:00</td> <td class="title">Mic dejun</td></tr>
<tr><td class="ora">12:00</td> <td class="title">Pranz</td></tr>
<tr><td class="ora">19:00</td> <td class="title">Cina</td></tr>
</tbody>

<tbody>
<tr><td class="ora">07:00</td> <td class="title">Mic dejun</td></tr>
<tr><td class="ora">12:00</td> <td class="title">Pranz</td></tr>
<tr><td class="ora">19:00</td> <td class="title">Cina</td></tr>
</tbody>

</div> // Inchide prima parte

##########

<div id="PARTEA-2"> // A 2 a parte

<tr>
<td class="data">luni (1.1.1970)</td>
<td class="data">marti (2.1.1970)</td>
<td class="data">miercuri (3.1.1970)</td>
<td class="data">joi (4.1.1970)</td>
<td class="data">vineri (5.1.1970)</td>
</tr>

<tbody>
<tr><td class="ora">20:00</td> <td class="title">Relaxare</td></tr>
<tr><td class="ora">24:00</td> <td class="title">Somn</td></tr>
<tr><td class="ora">06:00</td> <td class="title">Alarma</td></tr>
</tbody>

<tbody>
<tr><td class="ora">20:00</td> <td class="title">Relaxare</td></tr>
<tr><td class="ora">24:00</td> <td class="title">Somn</td></tr>
<tr><td class="ora">06:00</td> <td class="title">Alarma</td></tr>
</tbody>

<tbody>
<tr><td class="ora">20:00</td> <td class="title">Relaxare</td></tr>
<tr><td class="ora">24:00</td> <td class="title">Somn</td></tr>
<tr><td class="ora">06:00</td> <td class="title">Alarma</td></tr>
</tbody>

<tbody>
<tr><td class="ora">20:00</td> <td class="title">Relaxare</td></tr>
<tr><td class="ora">24:00</td> <td class="title">Somn</td></tr>
<tr><td class="ora">06:00</td> <td class="title">Alarma</td></tr>
</tbody>

<tbody>
<tr><td class="ora">20:00</td> <td class="title">Relaxare</td></tr>
<tr><td class="ora">24:00</td> <td class="title">Somn</td></tr>
<tr><td class="ora">06:00</td> <td class="title">Alarma</td></tr>
</tbody>

</div> // Inchide a 2 a parte

##########
```

Howdy,
I want to take data from a website with preg_match_all: DAY, TIME and TITLE. Each day is divided into two parts. I want to join the two parts in a single code, per individual day. Thank you in advance for any help.